# Google de-indexing http://fb://profile/profile-id

Tags: facebook, web, amp-html

http://fb://profile/profile-id violates AMP html policies and has led to Google de-indexing all of my web pages. How can I open my Facebook link on Facebook app when a user click Facebook icon on my site's footer using another way? I am using AMP version for mobile.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What error messages do you get after running [AMP validation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/preview_and_validate)?

> 1. Open your page in your browser.
> 2. Add "#development=1" to the URL, for example, http://localhost:8000/released.amp.html#development=1.
> 3. Open the Chrome DevTools console and check for validation errors.

One problem could be the protocol, use **https**. After updating the protocol and running validation, do you have any errors?